# how to deploy projects with maven and jboss?

Tags: apache-flex, maven, jboss

I am new to maven and Jboss(actually, never used other server as well)

I have a flex/blazDS/Java project with maven and jboss server. How can i deploy it?

PS: When i do the development, I used maven to build the project(using mvn clean install package ...).

then, go to my eclipse, right click the main app, let it run on my server.

Comment: You can write a Maven plugin to deploy your jars to JBoss, or you can configure a [continuous integration server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) to do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Maven JBoss Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/).  Once configured properly, you can use it to start and stop the server as well as deploy via JMX (for remote instances) and by hard-copying (for local instances).  As the guide states, first you would add the plugin to your pom:

```
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <jbossHome>/usr/jboss-4.2.3.GA</jbossHome>
          <serverName>all</serverName>
          <fileName>target/my-project.war</fileName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Make sure you customize the fields in the configuration section appropriately.  Then you can deploy to your JBoss server using (for remote)

```
mvn jboss deploy
```

or (for local)

```
mvn jboss hard-deploy
```

Answer (score 2):

The command is not jboss hard-deploy as given in above comment. The correct command to deploy using maven in jboss is 
**jboss:hard-deploy**